# Decoding Fock spaces

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, computational-complexity

Technically, the Fock space is (the Hilbert space completion of) the direct sum of the symmetric or antisymmetric tensors in the tensor powers of a single-particle Hilbert space H.(Wikipedia)

Question 1.How to write a Hilbert space if it is a Fock space as (the Hilbert space completion of) the direct sum of the symmetric or antisymmetric tensors in the tensor powers of a single-particle Hilbert space H. How to search for H, in computional-complexity sense?.Is there a general known method to search for H for any Fock space?.

Question 2.If there is not such method, could anyone give suggestions or ideas (not necessarily verified) how possibly to do that?.

Comment: I am perhaps still not quite understanding the issue: a Fock space is specified by a vacuum state $|0\rangle$ and a set of creation operators $a^\dagger_p$; the single-particle Hilbert space has basis states $a^\dagger_p|0\rangle$.

Comment: How is your already-give Fock space supposed to be specified?

Comment: I assume the Fock space is formed out of all linear combinations of states $a_{p_1}^\dagger a_{p_2}^\dagger\cdots a_{p_k}^\dagger|0\rangle$, $k=1,2,\ldots$.

Comment: I am asking how to write a Hilbert space if it is a Fock space as (the Hilbert space completion of) the direct sum of the symmetric or antisymmetric tensors in the tensor powers of a single-particle Hilbert space H. How to search for H?.

Comment: It seems to me that, if you are given a Fock space **with** its vacuum state and creation operators, then the first comment by @CarloBeenakker answers the question. If you're given only a Fock space, as an abstract Hilbert space, **without** a specified vacuum state and creation operators, then this is not enough information to recover the one-particle space $H$ as a subspace of Fock space. Even some non-isomorphic $H$'s can produce isomorphic Fock spaces. Example: any infinite-dimensional $H$ and any nontrivial finite-dimensional boson $H$ (i.e., use symmetric powers).

Comment: @AndreasBlass,I guess,since we are searching for H in computional-complexity context, H is a finite Hilbert space. Second, the question does not require uniqueness of H. I am not expert in any of all this.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, just for curiosity, what extra information we need to add to make H unique; if you know.

Comment: From a computational perspective that needs finite inputs and outputs, there's a problem because Fock spaces are often infinite-dimensional. Even if $H$ is one-dimensional (a spin-$0$ boson), the Fock space will be infinite dimensional because of the infinitely many possible occupation numbers. The only way the Fock space can be finite-dimensional is if you're dealing with fermions with a finite-dimensional $H$.

Comment: I don't see any plausible way to "find" $H$ within its Fock space by giving "simpler" information then just pointing out $H$. @CarloBeenakker has shown that the vacuum state and creation operators are enough information, but they describe a lot more than just $H$.

Comment: Sorry, in my questions and my comments; probably I am writing one thing and thinking completely about different thing. I am writing about Fock space as an object under computation, but in reality I am thinking about Fock space as a tool to do computation. So my question is wrongly phrased, instead I should write as the following:-  " Is there a general known method(scheme),to decode a quantum device;if we know about its Fock space,(we have information about its spectrum topology)".I am not sure if this good question,but this summaries  what I am thinking.